# Subtraction in Complex Number Geometry

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm starting just starting complex number geometry and I'm having trouble with understanding the basic theorems

if A, B, C, D are pairwise distinct points then

$\frac{d-c}{b-a} $ is purely imaginary, then AB is perpendicular to BC

I don't know how to prove this since I don't know what $d-c$ and $b-a$ represents in the graph

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a$ is the complex number represented geometrically by the vector $OA$, where $O$ is the origin, and similarly for $b, c, d$, then the difference $b-a$ is represented by the vector $AB$, and $d-c$ by $CD$. 
For concluding the exercise, note that multiplying a vector by $i$ is just rotation by $+90^\circ$.